How do I manual partition Kubuntu on my 1TB HDD
I want to use only Kubuntu on my laptop. I used a guide off YouTube the first time I did this but idk if it was correct or not since they used a 200GB HDD. And now I can't find any answer or guide of how to partition a 1TB HDD for Kubuntu. Can someone help me? English is not my first language and it's I'm not used to partitioning

Why not just let the install app do the partitioning?

Usually these kinds of questions are closed as opinion based. Do you want separate /home? Or separate data partition(s). Dual boot? I like multiple / partitions so I can install next LTS while still having working older LTS. So I then also keep data separate and mount in all installs. I may copy all settings from /home to new install, but sometimes may want to experiment in a temporary install.
My example, but many others depend on what you want and how much data your have. Note that I have not yet fully partitioned drive. And I do not have any snaps which can require a lot more space, like up to 20GB more in / (root).
MODEL                          NAME        FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED LABEL      PARTLABEL  MOUNTPOINT
Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB nvme0n1            465.8G                                         
                               ├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     512M  27.4M ESP_NVME   esp_nvme   /boot/efi  
                               ├─nvme0n1p2 ext4    29.3G  10.6G noble      noble      /          
                               ├─nvme0n1p3 ext4    29.3G        focal_k    focal_k               
                               ├─nvme0n1p4 ext4    29.3G        jammy      jammy                 
                               └─nvme0n1p5 ext4   195.3G 164.1G nvme_data  nvme_data  /mnt/data


You might wish to elaborate; tell what you have done and why. OP might be a novice.

To tell how to partition a system disk/drive for Linux...
I'd say this depends on WHAT you intend to do with the system.
A small system as indicated here (1TB) really benefits most from holding all data on the same partition; i.e. making it flexible w.r.t. storage capacity sharing among the system folders. Even avoid setting up more than /boot/ and / (root)
If you have one additional good-size disk to use, maybe mount that as /home instead of "wasting space" on the system disk.
Notably this has not much to do with partitioning.
(e.g. Google "move /home on Linux")
Best luck.

Usually these kinds of questions are closed as opinion based. Do you want separate /home? Or separate data partition(s). Dual boot? I like multiple / partitions so I can install next LTS while still having working older LTS. So I then also keep data separate and mount in all installs. I may copy all settings from /home to new install, but sometimes may want to experiment in a temporary install.

These kind of questions still need an answer; but yes - avoid OPINION. Explain, tell reasons why.
